# Is there some way to persist the terminal session to each project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to persist the terminal sessions for each project, separately, on VSCode. I know I can have the global terminal history but i would like to have the specific history of each project I'm working at the moment.
I just started programming, so this might be useless due to my ignorance. But right now, sounds helpful.

Comment: Which platform ? On Linux, tmux might let you do just that with attach and detach

Comment: I'm on Windows. I've heard of tmux but the sessions are lost when i turn my pc off, right? But yeah, sounds like the best choice at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: use a bash based terminal, it retains a large command history

Comment: Powershell persists its command history and is mostly compatible with CMD stuff. Not sure how to get VSCode to use that instead.